# Django - Create views and serialisers for table without model

Tags: python, django

I have a ManytoManyField in one of my model, Django automatically created a table in my database so there is no model for this table.

Here is my code:

```
class UserPortfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ExchangeConnection(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    portfolios = models.ManyToManyField(UserPortfolio, blank=True)
```

Django automatically created a table called `exchange_connection_portfolios` in my database which is fine.
But I don't know how to create DRF `Serialiser`s and `ViewSet`s without any model in my code.

Do I need to create a model for the table ?

Comment: How do you want your serializer json output to look like ?

Comment: Only an output that clearly shows related items. The table django created contains: `id`, `exchangeconnection_id`, `userportfolio_id`. So I would like to return all of these.

Comment: I also want it to appear in the `ExchangeConnection` serializer and in the `UserPortfolio` serializer.